Merging an unregistered account
Yesterday, I had a question and wanted to post it on Cryptography Stack Exchange. However, my VPN was down at that time, so I cannot log in with my existing account. I had no choice but to ask that question as an unregistered guest. When asked to provide an email address, I typed the one used to register my existing account without thinking about it. Since that account wasn't a user of this site, that email address was unused at that time, despite the fact that it has been used to create accounts on many other SE sites(SO, CV, EE, ...).
Soon, I made another mistake. When checking out the answers to that question on another computer, I joined this community with my existing account. That is to say, we have one email address used to create two accounts on this site.
Later, I checked my email inbox and tried to find the "Thanks for your post on Cryptography Stack Exchange" email sent to me when posting question as guest. However, when I click on the link, I was redirected to my old account (This make sense, for that email address has an account after my old account joined Cryptography).
Would you please tell me how can I recover the "overridden" guest account and merge it with my existing one? Thanks!

Did you have a look at the help-center?

As SEJPM's comment suggests, this page from the help center has all the info you need:

If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the contact form and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.


The problem is that I can't sign into both accounts. As far as I'm learnt, SE use email addresses to identify different accounts. However, in my case, these two account share a common email address.

Use the contact us form, and we'll send you more instructions on how we can get the accounts merged. Oh, and by the way, they don't share and e-mail address.
